# TMUX under Gentoo TTY artifacts

Tags: gentoo, tmux

Problem: Tmux.conf (included below) generates a statusbar... with a light gray background (the config says '#000000', so black). This background ends up replacing what would normally be the normal black background in (tested) Vim and Weechat.

My .bashrc says, to try making 256 colors work:

```
alias tmux='tmux -2'
```

When SSHing in to the computer from another machine (Ubuntu), no artifacting (the background being wrong) was observed, and the colours of the statusbar were correct.

When SSHing from the troubled computer to the machine that has no such problems, no artifacting was observed at all, and everything was correct.

Same with xterm on the troubled computer, no problems at all. Only in the virtual terminals is there a problem.

The troubled machine is a Gentoo computer, recently installed.

~/.tmux.conf:

```
# inprove colors Commenting this out had no effect.
# set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# soften status bar from harsh green to other colors
set  -g status-bg '#000000'
set  -g status-fg '#0077FF'

# administrative debris (I miss having a clock like on my mac)
set -g status-left '%a, %F'
set -g status-right '%H:%M:%S'

# Due to the accuracy of our time, update every second.
set -g status-interval 1

# Get the left side longer, to see the FULL date.
set -g status-left-length 16

# Center our status line
set -g status-justify centre

# Move our status line to the top.
set -g status-position top

# A new keybind, for reloading the config.
bind R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded..."

# monitor activity
setw -g monitor-activity on
 set -g visual-activity off

bind m setw monitor-activity off
bind M setw monitor-activity on
```

The $TERM variable inside a normal TTY (no tmux): `linux`
Inside TMUX: `screen-256color`

Obviously something is messed up. Any advice would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the artifacts, and actually get the whole colours thing working (just not the whole 256) I used `tmux` instead of `tmux -2`.